# Angular, object from factory not referenced

Tags: angularjs, api, factory

I have an AngularJS-Application with different controllers.

These controllers should share some of the data and I thought of using a factory for that:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['$http', 'dataService' function ($http, dataService) {
    var sharedData = {
        myData: null
    };

    var _loadData = function(){
        dataService.getData().then(
            function (response) {
                this.sharedData.myData = response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                //error-message
            }
        );
    };

    return {
        myData : sharedData,
        initData: _loadData()
    };
}]);
```

In my controllers I want to set and get that data like this:

```
$scope.init = function (){
    $scope.myData = myService;
    myService.initData();
};
```

The init will of course only be executed by one controller.

Sadly this doesn't work even though the data is correctly received from the dataService.

If I call the dataservice in my controller and then safe it to the factory everything works as expected:

```
$scope.init = function (){
    $scope.myData = myService;
    dataService.getData().then(
        function (response) {
            myService.myData = response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
            //error-message
        }
    );
};
```

Why does that happen? How can I move the querying logic to the factory and still have a reference to the sharedData-object that will be updated in all refrencing controllers whenever it changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bind the same data and make angular watch list watch correctly for your changes you should use a getter like function in your factory, in the controller you link the function to the $scope by reference only, and in your HTML you call this function to get the data.

check this fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23z8urzw/3/)

```
myApp.factory('myService',[function(){
    var _someData = {
        foo: "bar"
    };

    return {
       getData: function() {
         return _someData;
       },
       setData: function(data) {
        _someData = data;
       }
     }
  }]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.getData;
    $scope.setData = function () {
        myService.setData({from: 'mainCtrl'});
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('anotherCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.getData;
    $scope.setData = function () {
        myService.setData({from: 'anotherCtrl'});
    };
}]);
```

In your HTML:

```
<div>{{data()}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working jsfiddle demoing a solution

https://jsfiddle.net/u48vcw09/3/

Basically you have

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
    var that = {};
  that.sharedData = {};

  that.initData = function _loadData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function(data) {
        that.sharedData.data = response.data;
    });
  };

  that.initData();

  return that;
}]);
```

And here's the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SampleCtrl',
  ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.sharedData = myService.sharedData;
    };

    $scope.init();
}]);
```

If you can, it's best to load your data from within the factory code itself.

Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.